# Embedding IronPython in a WinForms app and interrupting execution

Tags: ironpython, python-embedding

### BACKGROUND

- I've successfully embedded IronPython in my WinForm apps using techniques like the one described here: http://blog.peterlesliemorris.com/archive/2010/05/19/embedding-ironpython-into-a-c-application.aspx
- In the context of the embedding, my user may any write loops, etc.
- I'm using the IronPython 2.6 (the IronPython for .NET 2.0 and IronPython for .NET 4.0)

### MY PROBLEM

- The users will need to interrupt the execution of their code
- In other words they need something like the ability to hit CTRL-C to halt execution when running Python or IronPython from the cmdline
- I want to add a button to the winform that when pressed halts the execution, but I'm not sure how to do this.

### MY QUESTION

- How can I make it to that pressing the a "stop" button will actually halt the execution of the using entered IronPython code?

### NOTES

- Note: I don't wish to simply throw away that "session" - I still want the user to be able to interact with session and access any results that were available before it was halted.
- I am assuming I will need to execute this in a separate thread, any guidance or sample code in doing this correctly will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is basically an adaptation of how the IronPython console handles Ctrl-C. If you want to check the source, it's in `BasicConsole` and `CommandLine.Run`.

First, start up the IronPython engine on a separate thread (as you assumed). When you go to run the user's code, wrap it in a `try ... catch(ThreadAbortException)` block:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
bool aborted = false;
try {
    engine.Execute(/* whatever */);
} catch(ThreadAbortException tae) {
    if(tae.ExceptionState is Microsoft.Scripting.KeyboardInterruptException) {
        Thread.ResetAbort();
        aborted = true;
    } else { throw; }
}

if(aborted) {
    // this is application-specific
}
```

Now, you'll need to keep a reference to the IronPython thread handy. Create a button handler on your form, and call `Thread.Abort()`.

```
public void StopButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pythonThread.Abort(new Microsoft.Scripting.KeyboardInterruptException(""));
}
```

The `KeyboardInterruptException` argument allows the Python thread to trap the `ThreadAbortException` and handle it as a `KeyboardInterrupt`.